# How to shift plots in x axis using matplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shift

I have 5 lists [er1, er2, er3, er4 and er5] (which can be converted into pandas dataframe) with lengths of 10, 9, 8, 7, 6

When I plot them by using this piece of code:

```
er1=[]
for i in range(0,10):    
    er1.append(mse(X[0:2,i],Y[0:2,i+1]))
    

plt.plot(er1, color='blue')

...  (here the same piece as above for the rest of lists

plt.show()
```

the result is the following

[image]

However, I want to shift er2 one position on the x-axis to the right, er3 two positions and so on. However, when I've tried er2.shift (on pandas) there is no change.

Did I miss something?

Comment: when you only specify the y values in `plt.plot(er1)` then x values will be `range(len(er1))`, so in order to shift the graph you need to specify x too, e.g. `range(1, len(er1)+1)` etc.

Comment: if, however, `er1` is a pandas series and not a list as shown in your example, then it should work as expected, i.e. the graph should be shifted, so you need to provide a self contained example of your issue.

Comment: where should I add this 'range(1, len(er1)+1)' inside the 'plt.plot(er1)' function?

Comment: `plt.plot(range(1, len(er1)+1), er1, color='b')`